# Finding the JSON file containing a particular key value , among multiple JSON files

Tags: python, json, pandas, cmd

So, I have 5 JSON files named as JSON1,JSON2,JSON3,JSON4 and JSON5. General format of these json files is

**General format of JSON files**

```
{
  "flower": {
    "price": {
      "type": "good",
      "value": 5282.0,
      "direction": "up"
     }
    },
  "furniture": {
    "price": {
      "type": "comfy",
      "value": 9074.0,
      "direction": "down"
     }
   }
}
```

Among all these json files , I need to find that json file which has a particular value/data given by the user. for eg- if the user gives an input for the **"value" = 9074** that it want to search in all the JSON files and gives an output as the JSON file which contains the value mentioned along with the line which has the mentioned data.

The approach I used was:

```
import json
with open('JSON1.json','r') as f1:
    item1 = json.load(f1)
with open('JSON2.json','r') as f1:
    item2 = json.load(f1)
with open('JSON3.json','r') as f1:
    item3 = json.load(f1)
with open('JSON4.json','r') as f1:
    item4 = json.load(f1)
with open('JSON5.json','r') as f1:
    item5 = json.load(f1)
# Input the value that user want to search
item = input("Enter the value:\n")

# function to search the json file
def search_json(value):
 int i = 0;
  for keyvalue in item(i+1):
    i++;
    if value == keyval['value']
      return keyvalue[name of the json file]

if(search_json(item) !=None):
 print("this value is present in json log :",search_json(item))
```

the output observed should be:

Enter the value: 9074

This value is present in json log **JSON1** and is present at **12** line of code

But, the above approach isn't efficient and correct . As, I'm new to learning python therefore I'm confused with the correct approach. It'll be really grateful if someone could help.

Comment: Your code doesn't work at all `item(i+1)` will not access the `itemX` variables.

Comment: `int i = 0;` ? This looks like a Java-Python mix up.

Comment: it's almost-certainly worth having an [LRU cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) on this too (EDIT: swapped link to _bounded_ cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the filenames.

```
def find_value_in_json_files(value, files):
    for f in files:
        with open(f) as f:
            item = json.load(f)
        for k, v in item.items():
            price = v['price']
            if price.get('value', price.get('values') == value:
                return f, k

print(find_value_in_json_files(9074, ['JSON1.json', 'JSON2.json', 'JSON3.json', 'JSON4.json', 'JSON5.json']))
```

Comment: @Barmer , facing this issue:                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                 
 in find_value_in_json_files(value, files)                                            
                 item = json.load(f)
           for k, v in item.items():
             if v['price']['value'] == value:
                     return f, k
     

KeyError: 'value'

Comment: Use `.get()` if the `value` key can be missing.

Comment: @Barmer thanks, it worked . Also, can you help, if suppose JSON2 json file had values as arrays....**"values" : [ 23, 76 ]** , while rest of the files have value as number-** "value" : 987**

Comment: Use an `if` statement to test whether there's a `values` or `value` key in the dictionary, then use the appropriate test (either `in` or `==)`.

Comment: @barmer , Didn't get what you meant. Can you show it , plz

Comment: @Barmer, will there be any change if instead of arrays , i choose list of scalar values

Comment: JSON arrays become Python lists.

Comment: @Barmer actually when I'm giving value as [ 83.0 , 56.0 ] , the result is coming None. Can you suugest, what could be the problem along with solution

Comment: If it's `"values": [83.0, 56.0]` and you're searching for `83` or `56` then it should work.

Comment: like in the JSON2 file                                                                                  `{
  "flower": {
    "price": {
      "type": "good",
      "values": [ 62.0,60,0 ]
      "direction": "up"
     }
    },
  "furniture": {
    "price": {
      "type": "comfy",
      "values": [ 83.0,56.0 ],
      "direction": "down"
     }
   }
}` this  how values are given . So, when I pass `print(find_value_in_json_files([ 83.0, 56.0 ], ['JSON1.json', 'JSON2.json', 'JSON3.json', 'JSON4.json', 'JSON5.json']))`  --- the output is coming **None** instead of JSON2 and furniture

Comment: My code only works for searching for a single number, not a list.

Comment: I've updated the code to allow searching for a list like that. But it won't work if the JSON contains `[83.0, 56.0]` and you search for `[56.0, 83.0]`. It's doing an exact match of the list, which is order-dependent.

Comment: Thanks, It worked to ....also, is it possible to take the input of value and values from the user itself rather than changing in the direct code